# guardar datos en un array con js

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

tengo dos variables con sus respectivos valores:

`lat = ["-100.41812896728515","-100.41812896728517","-100.41812896728519"]
 lng = ["20.62346622550882","20.623466225508828","20.623466225508828"]`

lo que quiero es unir ambos que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
nuevo_array = [
["-100.41812896728515","20.62346622550882"],
["-100.41812896728517","20.623466225508828"],
["-100.41812896728519","20.623466225508828"],
]
```

Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
 cords = [];
//  console.log("coord : " + typeof(lat));
for (let index = 0; index < lat.length; index++) {
    cords.push([parseFloat(lat[index]), '']);
    for (let index2 = 0; index2 < lng.length; index2++) {
        cords.push([cords[index], parseFloat(lng[index2])])
    }
}
```

cual seria la forma adecuada de lograr esto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas dos bucles, puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
lat = ["-100.41812896728515","-100.41812896728517","-100.41812896728519"]
 lng = ["20.62346622550882","20.623466225508828","20.623466225508828"]

 cords = [];
//  console.log("coord : " + typeof(lat));
for (let index = 0; index < lat.length; index++) {
    cords.push([parseFloat(lat[index]), parseFloat(lng[index])]);    
}

console.log(cords);
```